# list of tuples names and number as parameters and remove

Tags: python, function, tuples

Define a function named `update_contact(list_of_tuples, search_name, new_phone)` that takes `a list of tuples`, a name - `search_name` and a phone number-`new_phone` as parameters. The function updates an existing contact tuple in the list if the name exists in the list by removing the existing tuple and adding a new tuple to the end of the list using the parameter name and phone number. The function should also print a message to indicate the contact has been changed.

Note: if the parameter name does not exist, the function should

```
print ("xxx is not found.")
```

where xxx is the parameter name.

Note: you can assume that the contact list contains unique contacts only.

I'm learning tuples and this is really confusing, how do I approach this type of question?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. What exactly is confusing? What have you tried?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have written and tell us exactly which bit is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so let's start by defining what a tuple is: [Tuples are used to store multiple items in a single variable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp).

In your case you need a list of tuples; let's start by defining that

```
''' This is a list that contains 3 tuples and each tuple contain the contact name and 
     the phone number'''
contact_list = [('aaa', 123), ('bbb', 456), ('ccc', 789)]
```

The funcition `update_contact` is defined as such:

```
# Takes as parameters the list, the name to search for, and the new phone number
def update_contact(contact_list, search_name, new_phone): 
    '''
      Looping through the list (each iteration will give a tuple)
      - first iteration: i = ('aaa', 123)
      - second iteration: i = ('bbb', 456)
    '''
    for i in contact_list:
        '''         
          In order to get the name inside the tuple (Assuming that the name comes first 
          before the number) we access it using i[0]; 
          If we take the first iteration: i = ('aaa', 123), i[0] = 'aaa'
          and we compare it to search_name
        '''
        if i[0] == search_name:
            # If it matches we need to remove that tuple from the list 
            contact_list.remove(i)
            # And append the new tuple to that list
            contact_list.append((search_name, new_phone))
            # then return the new list
            return (contact_list)
    # return if search_name was not found in list
    return search_name + " Does not exist"
```

finally to call the function:

```
contact_list = update_contact(contact_list, 'bbb', 111)
print(contact_list)
```

Comment: Please, don't provide answers to people without effort on their part. This is not how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is simpler and faster to use dictionary to build the data structure.

```
def update_contact(list_of_tuples, search_name, new_phone):
    contact_dict = dict(list_of_tuples)
    if search_name in contact_dict:
        print(f"{search_name} is updated.")
    else:
        print(f"{search_name} is not found.")
    contact_dict.update(search_name=new_phone)
    return [(k, v) for k, v in contact_dict.items()]
```

The new inserted contact info is not really at the end since dictionary uses hash to store data.

I think this function should only use dict instead of list of tuple.

```
def update_contact(contact_dict, search_name, new_phone):
    if search_name in contact_dict:
        print(f"{search_name} is updated.")
    else:
        print(f"{search_name} is not found.")
    contact_dict.update(search_name=new_phone)
    return contact_dict
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your problem , we need list of tuples containing `name` and `phone number` of a person. We need to define `update` function. For this problem `dictionary` will be better approach(Name as key and Phone number as value) .But as you said , I tried to use list of tuples.

```
def update_contact(contacts,nm,phno):
    flag=0
    for c in contacts:
        if c[0]==nm:
            #to remove object from list
            contacts.remove(c)
            flag=1
    if flag==1:
        new=(nm,phno)
        #to append new tuple to list
        contacts.append(new)
    else:
        print("Name not found!!")
        
    
    return contacts

#existing list of tuples
contacts=[("Rahul","9111111111"),("Taylor","9112222211")]
print("Contacts:",contacts)
nm=input("Enter name to search :")
phno=int(input("Enter new phone number :"))
#calling function
print(" Updated Contacts: ",update_contact(contacts,nm,phno))
```